# protobuf-c: How to pack nested messages

Tags: c, protocol-buffers

I have a Protobuf Protocol file that looks something like this:

```
message Foo {
    message Bar {
        required string name = 1;
        required string value = 2;
    }

    message Baz {
        required Bar a = 1;
    }
}
```

Given this protocol file, I need to write an encoder using protobuf-c, the C extension for Protobuf. I wrote the following code:

```
Foo myfoo = FOO__INIT;
Foo__Bar mybar = FOO__BAR__INIT;
Foo__Baz mybaz = FOO__BAZ__INIT;
mybaz.a = &mybar;
```

However, I am stuck at this point on how to serialize `mybaz`. The generated struct for Foo, does not contain any entry that I can assign `mybaz` to. And no method for generated to directly pack Baz.

In Python, this was a lot more simpler, since a `mybaz.SerializeToString()` function had been generated. How should I go about this in C?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Declaring nested types in Protocol Buffers is like declaring nested classes in C++ or `static` inner classes in Java. This simply declares a new type; it does not add a field to the outer type. So, in your proto schema, `Foo` is a completely empty message -- it has no fields. This is true regardless of which programming language you're working in.

Probably what you meant to do is something like this:

```
message Foo {
  message Bar {
    required string name = 1;
    required string value = 2;
  }

  message Baz {
    required Bar a = 1;
  }

  optional Baz baz = 1;
}
```

Now `Foo` has a field called `baz` into which you can assign a `Baz` object.

Comment: This makes the most sense. However, sadly I don't control the proto file. The protocol has been designed by a third party and I must implement a client application using it. Using the standard C++ Protobuf library, it seems to work as expected.

Comment: @darnir On re-read, I think I misunderstood your original question. I was thrown off by "The generated struct for Foo, does not contain any entry that I can assign `mybaz` to." -- this is expected, given the type declaration. But it looks like what you're really looking for is a way to serialize a `Baz` structure directly. This should be provided by the generated code, but it's possible protobuf-c has a bug and doesn't generate any such function. I'd file a bug against them.